# Could anyone explicity show the following step?

Tags: integration, change-of-variable

How did the writer change from one integration to a double integration, and when can i do this?[image]

[image]

Comment: Isn't that just the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 yeah but theres an x on the btm in the left, but on the right there isnt

Comment: Only one of the variables in the exponent of that inner integral is actually a variable. The other is a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question,

$$
\int_{a}^{b}e^{(-x)t}dt = \frac{e^{(-x)t}}{-x} \Bigl|^{b}_{a} = \frac{e^{-x(b)} - e^{(-x)a}}{-x} = \frac{e^{-ax} - e^{-bx}}{x} 
$$

So the author just rewrote the right-hand side of the last equation as an integral. As noted, this is a very unusual move.

Answer (score 2):

This is not at all a typical move. As @TheChaz commented, the inner integral produces the integrand of the outer integral, by direct integration. It's not about double integrals, just about how to integrate $e^{-tx}$ from $a$ to $b$.

The *point* of doing this is surely less obvious... Context?

EDIT: recall that $\int_a^b e^{tx}\;dt = {e^{bx}-e^{ax}\over x}$.

Also, the peculiar feature of this general type of integral has a search-able name, "Frullani integral". It is not entirely trivial to justify the conclusion, but what you give is the standard heuristic, indeed.

Comment: I have updated the post to show full context

Comment: I have done the integration but the 1/x seems to be appearing out of nowhere.

Comment: what do you mean by not entirely trival Dr paul

Comment: Instead of $tx$ in the exponent, think of it as something like $kt$, where $k$ is a constant. The derivative would be $-k\exp{-kt}$ so to end up with no constant in front, you divide by the constant in the exponent

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard form of Frullani's integral.(You can find a proof [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d0Xwct0a-QI)). Basically, it says that -

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {f(ax) - f(bx)}{x} dx = \left(f(0) - \lim_{n \to \infty}  f(n)\right) \cdot \ln\left(\frac {b}{a}\right)$$

In your case, $f(x) = e^{-x}.$ Taking the limits we can see that the answer is $\ln(\frac {b}{a}).$